# Have System properties always values

Tags: java, system-properties

Do `System.getProperty("line.separator")` and `System.getProperty("os.name")` always have values?

Or do I need to check the return value in the code for `null`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are inserted automatically by the JVM

Answer (score 0):

The question is: can your code handle a null? If yes check for it, even if it is extremely unrealistic that this part of the code will ever be called, if not add a *if null -> terminate* concept, if that might cause trouble otherwise.

While the JVM will insert this for you, there are still two cases left where you can get null:

- The JVM has a bug
- Someone in the background deletes these properties.

None of these cases is likely enough to require to handle them by default.